# How can I see which processes on Windows XP are accessing the file system?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, process

Some process on my XP workstation is randomly clobbering performance for minutes or hours at a time with, I believe, a steady stream of hard drive access.

This does not seem to correlate to processes with heavy CPU usage, so is there a utility I can leave open that will show which processes are hitting the file system the most?

I don't know if the situation is reads, writes, or just checking metadata of files and folders.

This is a corporate laptop running up-to-date AV software, so it's far more likely to be the AV software than malware. Unfortunately, IT department has no answers, so I'm on my own here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (formerly filemon & regmon) should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

[Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)([direct link](http://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe)) from Sysinternals does exactly what you are looking for.